# Argument of type 'ReadableStream<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadableStream'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stream

I want to get a Readable form a Blob.

```
import {Readable} from 'stream';

const data: Blob = new Blob( );
const myReadable: Readable = (new Readable()).wrap(data.stream());
myReadable.pipe(ext);
```

I get This error

```
ERROR in src/app/features/recorder/components/record-panel/record-panel.component.ts:80:38 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'ReadableStream<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadableStream'.
  Type 'ReadableStream<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReadableStream': readable, read, setEncoding, pause, and 22 more.
```

I use Node 14 angular 10 and typescript

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two different definitions of `ReadableStream` in this code which are not compatible with each other.

---

`Blob` comes from the DOM typings.  `Blob.stream()` [returns](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/322c70fd8259b2beef001e1a346fc75ab070dbea/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L2613) a `ReadableStream<any>` as defined in `lib.dom.d.ts`:

```
interface ReadableStream<R = any> {
    readonly locked: boolean;
    cancel(reason?: any): Promise<void>;
    getReader(): ReadableStreamDefaultReader<R>;
    pipeThrough<T>(transform: ReadableWritablePair<T, R>, options?: StreamPipeOptions): ReadableStream<T>;
    pipeTo(dest: WritableStream<R>, options?: StreamPipeOptions): Promise<void>;
    tee(): [ReadableStream<R>, ReadableStream<R>];
}
```

[GitHub source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/322c70fd8259b2beef001e1a346fc75ab070dbea/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L12571)

---

`Readable.wrap()` [expects to be called with](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5dfa1a2690017d1d4eedf251548145661fa2c1e8/types/node/stream.d.ts#L50) a `ReadableStream` from the NodeJS definitions in `@types/node/globals.ts`:

```
interface ReadableStream extends EventEmitter {
    readable: boolean;
    read(size?: number): string | Buffer;
    setEncoding(encoding: BufferEncoding): this;
    pause(): this;
    resume(): this;
    isPaused(): boolean;
    pipe<T extends WritableStream>(destination: T, options?: { end?: boolean; }): T;
    unpipe(destination?: WritableStream): this;
    unshift(chunk: string | Uint8Array, encoding?: BufferEncoding): void;
    wrap(oldStream: ReadableStream): this;
    [Symbol.asyncIterator](): AsyncIterableIterator<string | Buffer>;
}
```

[GitHub source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/0a800f58b8df8b26f8f9e7ad00c3fbd6ee31a602/types/node/globals.d.ts#L443)

---

Your code attempts to assign a DOM `ReadableStream` to a function that requires a NodeJS `ReadableStream`.  You get a error telling you all of the properties that are expected from this Node version which aren't present in the DOM version variable `data.stream()`.

Comment: What would be the solution here then? Is there a way to get a `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>` into the node.js format? I have the same problem except the functionality works, its just the type that is complaining.

Comment: @liamlows I think you can use a type assertion?  `someVar as NodeJS.ReadableStream` or possibly `someVar as unknown as NodeJS.ReadableStream`

Comment: thanks that seemed to work! I was missing the `as unknown` chunk.

Comment: This same error can come up in other contexts, but require different typecasting - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614649/how-can-i-download-and-save-a-file-using-the-fetch-api-node-js/74722818#comment133510726_74722818 for another example of the same issue with a different solution.