# Typescript error converting a native fetch body webstream to a node stream

Tags: node.js, typescript, fetch-api, node-streams

**package.json**

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.6.5",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Using node v18.7.0, I am trying to convert a webstream returned from the native fetch API to a node stream.
I use Readable.fromWeb method from 'node:stream' module.
Typescript is returning a typecheck error but code is working as expected with a @ts-ignore comment.

**Type error**

```
 Argument of type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadableStream<any>'.
  Type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReadableStream<any>': values, [Symbol.asyncIterator]

const nodeStream = Readable.fromWeb(fetchRequest.body)
```

**Source code**

```js
import { Readable } from 'node:stream'
import { pipeline } from 'stream/promises'
import fs from 'fs'

const fetchRequest = await fetch('https://www.npmjs.com/')

if (fetchRequest.body) {
  // Argument of type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadableStream<any>'.
  // Type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReadableStream<any>': values, [Symbol.asyncIterator]
  // @ts-ignore
  const nodeStream = Readable.fromWeb(fetchRequest.body)

  await pipeline(nodeStream, fs.createWriteStream('output.html'))
}

export {}
```

Is there a bug with fetch typings or I am doing something wrong ?

[Here is a reproduction playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&jsx=0&ts=4.8.0-beta#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgJQKYEMAm6BGAbVOAXzgDMoIQ4ByAOwk1QC4BnGKDEagWAChRIsRHDDAwqPMFqES5SjTYd0IAPRgKIYC1Qse-cNHikWZDTWN6+AYwi02ZVDCsALNAEcArjvgBeOOgB3dGAjRxcACmpnGBgwFiYVFQDkgDpaMBAAKxYUm1VqAEo+PmBSOHDSMNdUT28UnAYATwLEPjg4Gzt4ekYAZXZOOD80LFwCFLkQAHVUHAqq9y82eqai3nbA4PhRcUlpcJ7UfqUQABoyHKslGFQpqBCjgeVIiA9Yt5TokDxCtZJi3ioAAegngCCIfCAA)

Comment: I've just found the same issue.  Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: i'm struggling with this typing issue also. i can add `//@ts-ignore` or `as unknown as Iterable<UInt8Array>` and code runs fine. just a typing issue it seems

Comment: Not a bug and this has already been answered before,  There are 2 differents definition of `ReadableSteam` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63630114/argument-of-type-readablestreamany-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-r

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your fetch is not the nodejs fetch, it's DOM fetch
@types/NodeJS doesn't have fetch
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/60924#issuecomment-1236920407

ThisIsNotTheFetchYouAreLookingFor.jpg

---

You may fix this with

```
import type * as streamWeb from 'node:stream/web';
declare global {
  interface Response {
    readonly body: streamWeb.ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null;
  }
}
```

as streamWeb.ReadableStream extends ReadableStream

, or using external definitions like in the linked thread

```
declare global {
    export const {
        fetch,
        FormData,
        Headers,
        Request,
        Response
    }: typeof import('undici')
    export type {FormData, Headers, Request, RequestInit, Response} from 'undici'
}

export {}
```